# GridPanel cannot get row index in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt

I am picking up somebody else's project and encounter an error ONLY IN INTERNET EXPLORER when I try to click on a row in GridPanel. I am able to get data showing correctly on the table but when I click on the row, wanting to get the row index to perform some other stuff, I get "null" for the row index on IE 7 and 8. No problem on FF, Chrome, Safari.

Message: '0' is null or not an object
Line: 10
Char: 1601
Code: 0
URI: http://mysite.com/Proj/js/ext/adapter/yui/ext-yui-adapter.js

Message: '0' is null or not an object
Line: 10
Char: 1601
Code: 0
URI: http://mysite.com/Proj/js/ext/adapter/yui/ext-yui-adapter.js

This is the code to generate the values in the gridPanel:

```
grid.getEl().mask("Searching for codes, please wait...", true);
    AsyncCallback<LinkedHashMap<Long, Map>> acb = new AsyncCallback<LinkedHashMap<Long, Map>>() {

        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
             grid.getEl().unmask();
            MessageBox.alert("Failed :" + caught.getMessage());
        }

        public void onSuccess(LinkedHashMap<Long, Map> result) {

            Set key = result.entrySet();
            Iterator it = key.iterator();
             grid.setVisible(true);

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry en = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                Map m = (Map) en.getValue();
                String code = m.get("code").toString();
                try {

                    Date activationDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(m.get("activationtime").toString()));
                    Date deactivationDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(m.get("deactivationtime").toString()));
                    String actDateF = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy KK:mm:ss").format(activationDate);
                    String deactDateF = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd-MM-yyyy KK:mm:ss").format(deactivationDate);

                    Object[] obj = new Object[]{
                        actDateF,
                        deactDateF,
                        code
                    };


                    Record record = recordDef.createRecord(obj);
                     grid.getStore().add(record);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    codeNotReading.add(code);
                    codeNotReading.add(e.getMessage());

                }
            }

            grid.getView().refresh();
            grid.getEl().unmask();
            if (codeNotReading.size() > 0) {
                MessageBox.alert(" \n Following code(s) cann't be added.  : " + codeNotReading.toString());
            }

        }
    };
```

and the code to get the row index:

```
grid.addGridCellListener(new GridCellListenerAdapter() {

      @Override
        public void onCellDblClick(GridPanel grid, int rowIndex, int colIndex, EventObject e) {                
            MessageBox.alert("Row "+rowIndex);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, your double click can occur iside the GridPanel and outside a row's cell. So the rowIndex would be null. I advise you to put a breakpoint on the line `MessageBox.alert("Row "+rowIndex);` and check if rowIndex is not negative or null.

If it is negative or null, then change thecode of **onCellDblClick** to the following:

```
if (rowIndex != null && rowIndex >= 0) {
    MessageBox.alert("Row "+rowIndex);
}
```

Comment: I debug line by line and managed to find out the problem. It was nothing to do with the GridPanel. It's the Rendering problem when I try to add <b> tags when adding data to cells. Not sure why though.